# FILTER function on column containing numbers, text and empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| 0 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Year | From | 1974 |
| 2 | 2004 | To | 2005 |
| 3 | 2016 | Result | 3 |
| 4 | 1996 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |
| 6 | no info |  |  |
| 7 | 1974 |  |  |
| 8 | no info |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |
| 11 |  |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |  |

---

In `Cell C3` I want to count the rows in `Column A` where the year is

a) >= the value in `Cell C1` AND 
b) <= the value in `Cell C2`

Therefore, I implemented this formula:

```
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$12,($A$2:$A$12>=C1))*($A$2:$A$12<=C2))
```

However, this formula returns `11` as result which is probably caused by the `empty cells` and the `no info` input in `Column A`.

To avoid that those inputs are considered in the count of the rows I tried to go with this:

```
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$12,($A$2:$A$12>=C1))*($A$2:$A$12<=C2)*($A$2:$A$12<>"")*($A$2:$A$12<>"no info"))
```

However, this formula still returns `11` as result.

How do I have to modify it to get the correct values?

Comment: I think your first formula is correct but due to wrong place of bracketing you are getting wrong result. Try `=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$12,($A$2:$A$12>=C1)*($A$2:$A$12<=C2)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put double close brackets `))` too early in your formula, ending the `Filter()` function and then putting additional conditions outside of it.

Change the formula to

```
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$12,($A$2:$A$12>=C1)*($A$2:$A$12<=C2)*($A$2:$A$12<>"")*($A$2:$A$12<>"no info")))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `COUNTIFS()`? Try-

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&C1,A:A,"<="&C2)
```

and with `FILTER()` try-

```
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$A$12,($A$2:$A$12>=C1)*($A$2:$A$12<=C2)))
```

[image]